# How to get the Last Day of the Current month using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I would like to know how can we fetch the Last day of the current month using javascript.
E.g. last day of January is **Tuesday**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var       today = new Date()
  , lastOfMonth = new Date( today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth()+1, 0 )
  ,   dayOfWeek = lastOfMonth.getDay();
```

`dayOfWeek` now = 0 for sunday... 6 for saturday